# Time offset at specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, offset, utc

I was wondering if anybody knows a function to convert UTC to local time but at the time the record was saved, not the time the script is being run.

Example:
I have a record saved in February and another one in August. Both are in UTC.
When I look at them through the application the February one shows the time -5 hrs and the August one shows the time -4 hours.
When I run a SQL script I need to see the same but using the T-SQL functions both show their time -5 hours (or -4 hours) depending when I run the script.

Analyzing the situation a bit further I realized it’s more complicated that what I thought.
There are 4 possibilities: The record saved during DST or ST and the SQL script being run during DST or ST.
If both are in DST or ST then I've just have to subtract the offset; if the record was saved in ST and the query is run in DST I'll have to subtract the offset – 1 but if it’s the other way around (record in DST and script run in ST) I should subtract the offset + 1.

Comment: Are you asking because when you run the script now, it may not reflect certain daylight saving rules depending on if the run date is in DST and the date being read was outside DST...?

Comment: Exactly.
The dates are saved in UTC and the convertion should happen regarding that date and not the time the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the UTC date was `2017-08-01 13:30:00` and I'm on the East Coast (US)

```
Select DateAdd(MINUTE, DateDiff(MINUTE, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()), '2017-08-01 13:30:00')
```

**Returns**

```
2017-08-01 09:30:00.000
```

Also, take a peek at `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`

Comment: It converts the date at the time the script runs, not the time the record was saved; so, the result is not the same if it's run during DST or not.

Comment: @LJ It will adjust for DST as your server adjusts for DST.  However, it it NOT a time machine.  Meaning it will only adjust for the CURRENT offset.